# Effective way to find the maximum points in an array with sufficent distance from each other with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have an array of number (like time series) and I want to certain number of high values. The high values (local maxima) should be far enough from each other. My solution:

1. find maxima in the whole arrray
2. clear surrounding around maxima (override the values with any small value)
3. repeat

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


MIN_DIST = 4
TO_FIND = 2

np.random.seed(103)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 20)
x[2] = 4
x[3] = 4.1
x[13] = 3.9



plt.plot(x)
plt.show()


locs = []
for idx in range(TO_FIND):
    loc = x.argmax()
    x[max(0,loc-MIN_DIST):min(loc+MIN_DIST,len(x))] = -2
    locs.append(loc)


print(locs)
```

[image]

Printed correct asnswer = 3, 13

In the example above there are two "too close values" - index 2 and 3 - so they should be counted only once as a maximum at index 3 (the bigger value). The second maxima I want to find is at index 13.

The code provided works well. However, I feel like it is really dumb way to do it. Is there any numpy or mathematical trick (even dirty tricky counts) on how to achieve it in a cheaper way?

**Amateur comparison to scipy.signal find_peaks:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import time
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

N = 10000
MIN_DIST = 4
TO_FIND = 2

t1 = 0
t2 = 0

correct = []
for k in range(N):
    y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
    y[3] = 5
    y[4] = 5.1
    y[11] = 4.9

#     plt.plot(y)
#     plt.show()

    t0 = time.time()
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=MIN_DIST)
    t1 += time.time() - t0

    t0 = time.time()
    x = y.copy()
    locs = []
    for idx in range(TO_FIND):
        loc = x.argmax()
        x[max(0,loc-MIN_DIST):min(loc+MIN_DIST,len(x))] = -2
        locs.append(loc)
    t2 += time.time() - t0

    same_answers = all([a == b for a, b in zip(locs, peaks[:TO_FIND])])

    correct.append(same_answers)

print("Correct (same answers):", all(correct))
print("find_peaks:", t1)
print("default:", t2)
```

find_peaks seems to be a bit slower:

> Correct (same answers): True
>
> find_peaks: 3.137294292449951
>
> default: 0.8532450199127197

Also if I remove the "fake samples" and the maxima there are not so clear, the results are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [this solution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) from scipy:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

np.random.seed(103)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 20)
x[2] = 4
x[3] = 4.1
x[13] = 3.9

MIN_DIST = 4
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=MIN_DIST, height=3)
peaks
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However, I am unable to provide this function with a number of peaks I want (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html did I miss something?). Also if I check how works the `_select_by_peak_distance` https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx - it seems somehow more complicated than my solution -  - please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: I find find_peaks the cleanest solution... u can set every kind of threshold and parameter... to get simply N peaks you can simply do peaks[:N] (from my code)

Comment: I agree fully, the adjustability is great in most cases. However for my specific case the peaks[:N] returns somehow incorrect solution - different from my required solution.

Comment: FIY - I updated my question to support my objections